# Get value from regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

how could I get value from regexp?

```
var str = '<tag>VALUE</tag>'; // VALUE
```

Comment: This question is vague. How fixed is that input? Will it always be the same tag, and exactly one tag? You could just use basic string operations for that.

Comment: Why would you even want to use regular expressions for this? Unless you're keeping something from us?

Comment: Must be a homework assignment. This is almost identical to another question this morning.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168885/regex-c-problem-with-matching

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal Sorry, it wlll be the exactly one tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your string is really that simple, you could simply get rid of the tags:

```
var str = '<tag>VALUE</tag>';

str = str.replace(/<tag>|<\/tag>/g,'');
```

If it is actually more complex or variable, then a regex may not be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

use groups:

```
var m = /<[^>]+>([^<]*)<\/[^>]+>/.exec('<tag>VALUE</tag>');
var s = m[1]
```

Comment: Mixture of Perl and JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Matching anything between > and <

```
"(?<=\>)(.*?)(?=\<)"
```